# Using functions within the count function in EXCEL?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to get counts of different values based on very specific criteria but I cannot seem to find a way to do it with the count function.

One of the more complicated counts I'm trying to get is comparing the value of an individual cell that uses the SUBSTITUTION() function (to alter it's value) to a static value in another cell.  But I cannot find any way to use the SUBSTITUTION() function within the condition field of any of the COUNT() functions in order to do this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data with expected results

Comment: @barryhoudini is correct. This seems like it might be solvable without too much trouble if some example data and results are posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try `=COUNTIF(Range, Criteria)` if it is just one criteria for multiple criteria use `=COUNTIFS (range1, criteria1, [range2], [criteria2], ...)`

Example:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A5,"abc") or COUNTIF(A1:A5,">0")
=COUNTIFS(A1:A5,"abc",B1:B5,">0")
```

Applies To: Excel 2016 Excel 2013 Excel 2010 Excel 2007 Excel 2016 for Mac Excel for Mac 2011 Excel Online Excel for iPad Excel Web App Excel for iPhone Excel for Android tablets Excel for Android phones Excel Mobile Excel Starter 2010 Less